# Filling an area in a graph positionned with the positionning library

Tags: tikz-pgf

to me the following MWE should work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xunicode}% for XeTex!
\usepackage{fontspec}% for XeTex!
\usepackage{xltxtra} % for XeTex!

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex−text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont [Mapping=tex−text]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont [Mapping=tex−text]{Inconsolata}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[note/.style={draw,black,circle,inner sep=2mm},
label distance=-1mm,label position=below left,
double distance=.5mm]
\node[note,double]      (C)  [label=Do   ] {};
\node[note,left=of C]   (F)  [label=Fa   ] {};
\node[note,right=of C]  (G)  [label=Sol  ] {};
\node[note,right=of G]  (D)  [label=Ré   ] {};

\node[note,above=of F]  (A)  [label=La   ] {};
\node[note,right=of A]  (E)  [label=Mi   ] {};
\node[note,right=of E]  (B)  [label=Si   ] {};
\node[note,right=of B]  (Fd) [label= Fa♯] {};

\node[note,above=of A]  (Cd) [label= Do♯] {};
\node[note,right=of Cd] (Gd) [label=Sol♯] {};
\node[note,right=of Gd] (Dd) [label= Ré♯] {};
\node[note,right=of Dd] (Ad) [label= La♯] {};

%\draw (F)  -- (C)  -- (G)  -- (D);
%\draw (A)  -- (E)  -- (B)  -- (Fd);
%\draw (Cd) -- (Gd) -- (Dd) -- (Ad);
%
%\draw (F) -- (A)  -- (Cd);
%\draw (C) -- (E)  -- (Gd);
%\draw (G) -- (B)  -- (Dd);
%\draw (D) -- (Fd) -- (Ad);

\begin{scope}[fill=black!50]
\filldraw (C) -- (E)  -- (G) -- cycle; % DOM
\filldraw (A) -- (Cd) -- (E) -- cycle; % LAm
\end{scope}

\draw[dashed] (Cd.north) -- +(0cm ,6mm );
\draw[dashed] (Gd.north) -- +(0cm ,6mm );
\draw[dashed] (Dd.north) -- +(0cm ,6mm );
\draw[dashed] (Ad.north) -- +(0cm ,6mm );
\draw[dashed] (F.south)  -- +(0cm ,-6mm);
\draw[dashed] (C.south)  -- +(0cm ,-6mm);
\draw[dashed] (G.south)  -- +(0cm ,-6mm);
\draw[dashed] (D.south)  -- +(0cm ,-6mm);
\draw[dashed] (F.west)   -- +(-6mm,0cm );
\draw[dashed] (A.west)   -- +(-6mm,0cm );
\draw[dashed] (Cd.west)  -- +(-6mm,0cm );
\draw[dashed] (Ad.east)  -- +(6mm ,0cm );
\draw[dashed] (Fd.east)  -- +(6mm ,0cm );
\draw[dashed] (D.east)   -- +(6mm ,0cm );
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But I do not get the desired result, that is 2 filled triangles with `black!50`.
Instead I get this :
[image: Cayley graph]

Any reason why? Do you get the same result?

Comment: You can try `\filldraw (C.center) -- (E.center)  -- (G.center) -- cycle;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xunicode}% for XeTex!
\usepackage{fontspec}% for XeTex!
\usepackage{xltxtra} % for XeTex!

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex−text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont [Mapping=tex−text]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont [Mapping=tex−text]{Inconsolata}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[note/.style={draw,black,circle,inner sep=2mm},
label distance=-1mm,label position=below left,
double distance=.5mm]
\node[note,double]      (C)  [label=Do   ] {};
\node[note,left=of C]   (F)  [label=Fa   ] {};
\node[note,right=of C]  (G)  [label=Sol  ] {};
\node[note,right=of G]  (D)  [label=Ré   ] {};

\node[note,above=of F]  (A)  [label=La   ] {};
\node[note,right=of A]  (E)  [label=Mi   ] {};
\node[note,right=of E]  (B)  [label=Si   ] {};
\node[note,right=of B]  (Fd) [label= Fa♯] {};

\node[note,above=of A]  (Cd) [label= Do♯] {};
\node[note,right=of Cd] (Gd) [label=Sol♯] {};
\node[note,right=of Gd] (Dd) [label= Ré♯] {};
\node[note,right=of Dd] (Ad) [label= La♯] {};

%\draw (F)  -- (C)  -- (G)  -- (D);
%\draw (A)  -- (E)  -- (B)  -- (Fd);
%\draw (Cd) -- (Gd) -- (Dd) -- (Ad);
%
%\draw (F) -- (A)  -- (Cd);
%\draw (C) -- (E)  -- (Gd);
%\draw (G) -- (B)  -- (Dd);
%\draw (D) -- (Fd) -- (Ad);

\begin{scope}[fill=black!50]
\filldraw[opacity=.5] (C.center) -- (E.center)  -- (G.center) -- cycle; % DOM
\filldraw[opacity=.5]  (A.center) -- (Cd.center) -- (E.center) -- cycle; % LAm
\end{scope}

\draw[dashed] (Cd.north) -- +(0cm ,6mm );
\draw[dashed] (Gd.north) -- +(0cm ,6mm );
\draw[dashed] (Dd.north) -- +(0cm ,6mm );
\draw[dashed] (Ad.north) -- +(0cm ,6mm );
\draw[dashed] (F.south)  -- +(0cm ,-6mm);
\draw[dashed] (C.south)  -- +(0cm ,-6mm);
\draw[dashed] (G.south)  -- +(0cm ,-6mm);
\draw[dashed] (D.south)  -- +(0cm ,-6mm);
\draw[dashed] (F.west)   -- +(-6mm,0cm );
\draw[dashed] (A.west)   -- +(-6mm,0cm );
\draw[dashed] (Cd.west)  -- +(-6mm,0cm );
\draw[dashed] (Ad.east)  -- +(6mm ,0cm );
\draw[dashed] (Fd.east)  -- +(6mm ,0cm );
\draw[dashed] (D.east)   -- +(6mm ,0cm );
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! I still don't get why it doesn't work without pointing to centers, but if it works, I buy :)

Answer (score 5):

This issue comes up pretty often so maybe a little explanation would be suitable. When fill command is issued on open paths, TikZ automatically connects the last received point of the path with the first point of the path and fills that region (as if `--cycle;` is put). So

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=blue!10, draw=red,thick] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gives

[image]

When we use `fill` on a line, it still closes the path but the result is a line again so we don't see anything regarding the fill.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=blue!10, draw=red,thick] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Now when we connect node shapes, TikZ kicks in a slightly complicated border shape calculation mechanism and it connects only the collinear points on both nodes' border, in other words it doesn't use the nodes coordinates but calculates the border locations

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] (a) at (0,0) {a};
\node[draw] (b) at (1,2) {b};
\draw[draw=red,thick] (0,0) -- (1,2) ;
\draw[draw=blue,ultra thick] (a) -- (b) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

So continuing this path to another node gives us:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] (a) at (0,0) {a};
\node[draw] (b) at (1,2) {b};
\node[draw] (c) at (2,0) {c};
\draw[draw=red,thick] (0,0) -- (1,2) -- (2,0);
\draw[draw=blue,ultra thick] (a) -- (b) --(c);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Hence, if we use nodes as coordinates we obtain two disjoint lines but when we use coordinates we get a continuous path. So, when a fill is issued on these paths, the first one creates two filled lines which are obviously invisible, but the second one behaves as expected.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] (a) at (0,0) {a};
\node[draw] (b) at (1,2) {b};
\node[draw] (c) at (2,0) {c};
\draw[fill=blue!10,draw=red,thick] (0,0) -- (1,2) -- (2,0);
\draw[fill=black!10,draw=blue,ultra thick] (a) -- (b) --(c);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

That's why using `(node.center)` works but `(node)` doesn't since anchors are also fixed coordinates while node shapes are usually not (except if the node is a `\coordinate` which has the node shape of a point.)